# Serve both Rails-generated views and Angular templates from the same Rails+Angular project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails app with an AngularJS front end. For the main app, Angular handles the routing and serves the templates, but I'd like to serve Rails-generated views as well on the same project.

Why? I haven't found out an easy way to use Rails helpers and assets in Angular templates.
If I try to load Rails views with Rails routing, Angular immediately takes control and displays a blank page.

I'm pretty new to this technology stack (and web programming in general), so sorry if this is a very basic question, I didn't find any information on the internet about this.

This is my folder structure:

```
app
--assets
----javascripts // here lives the Angular app
------controllers // Angular controllers
------templates // Angular templates
   ...
--controllers // Rails controllers
--views // Rails views
   ...
```

Comment: You really don't want to work with rails helpers and routes once you are in angular. You use rails routes to call the controller and serve up the template that loads up angular... from there, you use angular. That means you'll need to understand how to have angular call rails controllers for data, and on the rails side you'll need to respond with json rather than setting instance variables as you normally would.

Comment: @Nathan what about things like I18n translations, Devise login/signup pages and image assets? These are usually handled by Rails. Plus, can't I just do a quick Rails scaffolding for testing a new feature, for instance? Every view must be served by Angular now?

Comment: Angular has its own I18n translation capability: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n , as for assets.. those are just urls that you can reference in your angular templates. If you're looking to build a 100% single page app using angular, then you will need to interact with devise as an api, so you will need to build your own view templates in angular. However some people have a hybrid app where they login using rails templates and then route to the angular app. I don't recommend this.

Comment: Here is a free course I've found very helpful when getting started with this stuff: http://code.tutsplus.com/courses/hands-on-angular